# Weird line style for no reason (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a 3D-Box with HTML/CSS and for some reason, the lines I add have some weird shadowing/3D-effect themselves:
[image]

My only attempt to solve the issue was to google it because my HTML skills are very limited but could not find anything of help.

This is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

header {
  background: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

.outerDiv {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 7vw;
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1.1px solid red;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans";
}

.backbox {
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.frontbox {
  top: 7vh;
  left: 7vw;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.diagonal {
  width: 28.3px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 20% 40%;
}

.diagonal_left {
  top: -16px;
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}

.diagonal_right {
  top: 83%;
  left: -21%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="box frontbox">
    <hr class="diagonal diagonal_left">
    <hr class="diagonal diagonal_right">
    <p>hi</p>
    <div class="box backbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried reset border on `hr {border:0;border-top/* or bottom*/:solid 1px}` ?

Comment: no, I didn't, but it worked! thanks! I tried ``border: 1px solid black`` because I thought that was the way to format hr lines. but your solution was unexpectedly easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because for `hr` elements, the `border-style` is set to `inset` by default. Just add this to your css, to get the expected result:

```
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

This will set the border style to `solid` (which is the default for `div` elements), and show the border only for one edge.